# Mapping POJOs and Using Reference in MongoDB using Morphia

Tags: mongodb, mapping, morphia

I have two model classes. One is Company.java, another is HumanResource.java.

Company.java

```
@Entity("companies")
public class Company {
@Id
private ObjectId id = new ObjectId();
private String companyName;
private String emailAddress;
private String pictureUrl;
@Reference
private List<HumanResource> humanResources;
...
```

HumanResource.java

```
@Entity("humanresources")
public class HumanResource {
@Id
private ObjectId id = new ObjectId();
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String emailAddress;
@Reference
private Company company;
...
```

What I want to achieve is when I save a list of companies to datastore, related list of human resources documents should be inserted automatically.

In addition, I declared

```
@Id
private ObjectId id = new ObjectId();
```

in every model class. Is it a good way or should I change it ?

Comment: But how will you populate the company of the HumanResource when creating a company or vice versa? Also please post your collections schema

Comment: Company collection is populated with the reference of list of HumanResources. However, HumanResources collection is not populated in db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Morphia will not call `save()` on those references.  You must call `save()` on the instances you want to persist.  You can pass in a list of instances so you needn't loop, necessarily, but each instance needs to get passed in explicitly.

Comment: I got it. It works thank you. I have another question. I declared private ObjectId id = new ObjectId(); in every model classes. Is it a good way or should I change it ?

Comment: Morphia/the driver will populate the ID field for you as long as it's an ObjectId.  But there's no harm in creating the ID manually.  It's just unnecessary most of the time.

Comment: When I save one object without any references it populates. However, in this example, when I don't create manually, @id field cannot be null and mapping exception thrown

Comment: Referenced entities must be saved before you can save entities that reference them.  More completely, referenced entities must have a non-null ID value with which to build the reference value.  If you're manually creating IDs as part of the constructor, that will get used.  If you're relying on the driver creating that ID, you have to save the referenced entity first so that the ID will have been created when you save the referencing entity.

Comment: I got it. In this case, two entities have referenced each other. So I need to create ObjectId manually. Is it correct ?

Comment: That's probably simplest.  Otherwise you'd have to save each entity, add each to the other, then save them all over again.